# Finding a flag through 1000 base64 encoded files in a directory

Tags: unix

I have been trying to figure this out. I have 1000 files in a directory which are base64 encoded and I have been trying to find a "flag" through it. I have really been struggling to approach this and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What is _a "flag"_?

Comment: Password hidden in a file.

Comment: Can _Password_ be placed at any file offset?

Comment: Yep, the password is encoded in one of 1000 files and we have to decode them and find it

Comment: That does not answer the question whether the password can appear at any offset in the one file.

Comment: Yes, it can appear at any offset.

Comment: Do the files have more than one line?

Comment: No, they do not.

Comment: What is the minimum and the maximum length of the password?

Answer (score 0):

Of course we could decode all files and grep the "flag" in the decoded data, but it sounds like you want to avoid that. Another, perhaps more efficient approach is to find (a part of) the encoded "flag" in the files and then decode only the few candidate files (if more than one at all) to make sure which contains the exact "flag". Since three input bytes are encoded to four Base64 characters, a group of four in a Base64 file must start at one of three positions in the original "flag"; for example, with the "flag" `Password`, the Base64 file must contain one of the encodings of `Passwo`, `asswor` or `ssword`; so we can build these encodings and grep them in the unmodified encoded files.

```
f=${1?usage: $0 Password File...}
shift
l=`expr length "$f" / 3 \* 3`
s1=`expr substr "$f" 1 $l | tr -d '\n' | base64`
s2=`expr substr "$f" 2 $l | tr -d '\n' | base64`
s3=`expr substr "$f" 3 $l | tr -d '\n' | base64`
for file in `grep -l -e $s1 -e $s2 -e $s3 "$@"`
do  if base64 -d "$file" | grep -Fq "$f"
    then    echo "$file"
    fi
done
```